# creating a file dynamically

Tags: linux, shell

I want to save a few lines as a file etl.xml
I tried the following but it is not working for obvious reasons.

```
cat etl.xml << myscript
<etl>
    <connection id="in" driver="xpath" url="/home/test.xml"/>
        <query connection-id="in">
               /TXNEXP/AUTHADV
         <script connection-id="db">
    </script>
    </query>
 </etl>
myscript
```

Comment: @Nerian: Shouldn't that be an answer (with a bit of explanation)?

Comment: @delnan Done :)  ask if you need further clarification

Comment: I would recommend using a here doc marker that stands out visually from the rest of the text. `EOF` is often used. If you want it to be a little more descriptive, perhaps `EOF-myscript`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need one more character:

```
508 $ cat xmlhere.sh 
#!/bin/bash

cat > etl.xml << myscript
<etl>
    <connection id="in" driver="xpath" url="/home/XXX/WAVtxnexp20101125.xml"/>
        <query connection-id="in">
               /TXNEXP/AUTHADV
         <script connection-id="db">
    </script>
    </query>
 </etl>
myscript
```

This is a "here document".

Comment: Thanks. Can you please remove the username after /home/ for security reasons.

Comment: @shantanuo It's still visible in edits history (both question & answer)... If your security depends on obfuscation... bad things will happen ;)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to use some end marker. In that case, the syntax is "cat > outputfile << end_marker":

```
$ cat > etl.xml << EOF
here I write the file contents
EOF
```

If, instead, you want to append the line "myscript" to etl.xml, then:

```
$ echo myscript >> etl.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
cat myscript > etl.xml
```

or

```
echo myscript > etl.xml
```

The flow is:

origin > destiny

Overwrite the contents >

Append >>